# How to open a Connection Channel to connect to a GE PLC

Tags: networking, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, plc

I'm having trouble opening a connection between  my WPF application in Visual Studio to a PLC. I'm trying to use the TCP client class but the PLC denies me connection. I'm not to sure why this is happening can someone help?

Comment: This is not related to wpf in any way.  Your problem simply lies in your inability to open a communications channel to your PLC.

Comment: yes i know that I'm using the tcp client class but a connection wont open.

Comment: My comment was a reference to your post title and the use of the WPF tag.  The post has now been updated to remove this implied relationship, but note that you are most likely to get a response if you can exclude anything that is not absolutely pertinent to the problem.

Comment: Are you sure there are no networking issues, i.e. correct subnets, gateways, IP Addresses, or possibly port routing issues?  Wireshark on the PLC's side can help diagnose some of these, or at least eliminate them as possible issues, and also give you some knowledge as to what the PLC and your C# program are actually doing.